# Restrictions on function domain -- word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose you're to build a $200~\text{m}^3$ fuel tank that has a cylindrical middle part with hemispheres at each end. Suppose you're given the restriction that the maximum allowable length of the tank is $16~\text{m}$ measured from the tips of each hemisphere. The problem is to find the restriction on the radius of the hemispheres and of the base of the cylinder. My work so far:

$2r+h\le16$ where $h$ is the length of the cylinder part of the tank and $r$ is the radius of the hemispheres and the radius of the base of the cylinder.

$\pi r^2h+\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=200$ (volume of the tank in terms of $r$ and $h$)

$h=\frac{600-4\pi r^3}{3\pi r^2}$ (isolating $h$)

$2r+\frac{600-4\pi r^3}{3\pi r^2}\le16$ (substituting $h$ into the inequality)

Using CAS, I'm getting $2.08\le r \le 23.83$

This answer clearly doesn't make sense given that $2r+h\le16$

Can someone point out my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: We need $h\ge 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Based on your hint, I did $\frac{600-4\pi r^3}{3\pi r^2}\ge 0$, so that $0 < r \le 3.63$, so that makes sense now. But how are you supposed to predict that $h \ge 0$? How do you know that (meaning, how did you think of that)??

Comment: Just looked at the problem from a concrete point of view. We need to do better than $r\gt 0$, very small $r$ is not possible.

Comment: Well I suppose if you look at $\pi r^2 h + \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = 200$, it's possible for $h$ to be negative, so you're right we need to restrict that. But I'm not sure why you say that very small $r$ is not possible though. $r$ could be very small with $h$ approaching 16, no?

Comment: Bad on volume.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! If $r$ is very small and $h$ can only be 16, you'd never reach a volume of 200! Thanks!

Comment: The smallest $r$ was already computed by you, it is approximately $2.08$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, there's so many things going on I lost track ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest possible $r$ is when there is no cylindrical part. In that case we have $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=200$, so $r=\left(\frac{600}{4\pi}\right)^{1/3}$. Call this number $r_{\text{max}}$. If we *must* have a cylindrical part of non-zero length, then we have the bound $r\lt  r_{\text{max}}$.

The minimum $r_{\text{min}}$ is obtained by solving the equation 
$\pi r^2(16-2r)+\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=200$.  This cubic is best solved numerically. The value is, as you wrote, approximately $2.08$.

The minimum value of $h$ is $0$. The maximum value is $16-2r_{\text{max}}$.